# Meaning of the “Have you ever been refused entry or deported from any country, including Singapore?” question

Tags: visas, international-travel, terminology, singapore, denial-of-entry

I was denied a visitor visa for Singapore (reason unknown). Now when asked:

> Have you ever been refused entry or deported from any country, including Singapore?

do I check `Yes`? In other words, does 'entry denial' include visa rejection too (or just being turned back at the airport, etc.)?

Comment: When you are turned away you need to ask if you are being denied entry. Often when people are not allowed into Canada they are "allowed to withdraw their application" which means they can truthfully say no, they have not been denied. The people who refused your visa can tell you if that constituted denying you entry.

Comment: So to be clear, you applied for a visa outside Singapore, and did not receive it?  And never tried to enter Singapore?

Comment: If you were 'turned back' at the airport in Singapore, then you were refused entry.  It's uniform across all the Commonwealth nations.

Comment: Thanks all, I think I have a clearer picture now. Though I did find on the website, a visa may be rejected again,if it was rejected in recent times. So I am hoping it won't affect my visa application for this time


Thanks again for your response

Answer (score 7):

On the [Singapore Visa Application page](http://www.ica.gov.sg/services_centre_overview.aspx?pageid=252&secid=165), under important notes is the following statement:

> A Singapore visa is not an immigration pass.  It is a pre-entry permission for the holder of a valid Singapore visa to travel to, and seek entry, into Singapore.  The grant of an immigration pass will be determined by the Immigration & Checkpoints Authority (ICA) officers at the point of entry. Possession of a valid visa alone does not guarantee entry into Singapore.

This would seem to indicate that a denied visa is not a refused entry. After all, they are saying their visa is simply a means to travel to Singapore and **seek entry** into it.

Contacting the consulate for your country would, of course, be preferable.

Also, remember that they are asking if you have ever been deported from or refused entry to **any other country** as well. Other countries may consider a visa refusal/denial as *refused entry*.

Comment: Thanks all, I think I have a clearer picture now. Though I did find on the website, a visa may be rejected again,if it was rejected in recent times. So I am hoping it won't affect my visa application for this time


Thanks again for your response

Comment: seems weird. So you need to get a visa to be allowed to talk to an immigration officer who then determines if you'll get a visa. Legal mumbo jumbo of course. Same as in all countries, they just say that even with a valid visa you can still be denied entry if immigration finds a problem.

Comment: @jwenting All countries that I'm aware of have the same policy: just because you've been granted a visa doesn't *guarantee* that you'll be allowed to enter.  Specifically, in the Singaporean context, a "pass" means a right of residence (work pass, student pass etc) that lets you enter and exit Singapore at will.

Comment: @jpatokal yes. Wasn't questioning the practice, only the wording.